# How can I use header in css file

Tags: html, css, header

I have an external CSS file name main.css. The ID of nav and footer are working fine but the ID of header doesn't work. When I put the header part in HTML file, it works.
Why does it not work in CSS file.

HTML File:

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
        </head>    
        <body>    
            <div id="header">
                <h1>Furkan İlhan</h1>
            </div>
            
            <div id="nav">
                Hakkında<br>
                Kariyer<br>
            </div>
        
            <div id="footer">
            Tüm Hakkı Saklıdır. Furkanilhan.com
            </div>
        </body>    
        </html>
```

CSS File:

```css
    <style>        
        #header {
            background-color:black;
            color:white;
            text-align:center;
            padding:5px;            
        }
        
        #nav {
            line-height:30px;
            background-color:#eeeeee;
            height:300px;
            width:100px;
            float:left;
            padding:5px;    
        }
        
        #footer {
            background-color:black;
            color:white;
            clear:both;
            text-align:center;
            padding:5px;
        }
    </style>
```

[The image of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK5gm.png)

Comment: you have defined header as class and referring it in css using #header..use .header and it will work

Comment: Is the css in the same file

Comment: it is working for me in my text editor , you need to check on your end

Comment: yes it is in the same file. all others are work fine but only #header is not work. you can see in the image below @PranavKumar

Comment: is the issue resolved @Furkanİlhan

Comment: @DhavalChheda yes I have deleted style in the css file and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Dhaval is wrong - You had it right with the #header since you have it as an id in your HTML.
2. remove the `<style></style>` tags from your CSS sheet.

Let me know how you go

Regards,
Kostantinos

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 3):

Because You Use  class="header" Property And External CSS Defined ID # Header.

So You Change

#header {

}

Use This Code In CSS

.header {

}

Work 100% Perfectly

Answer (score 0):

It seems the links require id to be defined in each `<div></div>` to work, not just the class name.

My case was a bit different, where the links didn't work with just class defined  in html and  .clasname defined  in css file.